# Is there any way to restore / rebuild EFI without using a Windows bootable DVD?

Tags: windows, boot, efi

I've got a frustrating problem with some old hardware.  Due to some awfully designed firmware which hasn't had a new release since 2016, I can't boot from a USB stick containing an unpartitioned [UDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Disk_Format) filesystem (or similar).  The firmware will only accept that on physical DVD.

I've tried converting the Windows image into FAT32, but there's a file greater than 4GB so it won't fit on FAT32.

To make matters worse I don't have a dual-layer DVD burner and MS Windows ISOs are larger than single layer DVDs.

All I'm actually trying to achieve is to restore the boot loader into EFI which accidentally got deleted by a dual boot OS.

I have both Linux and Mac machines available. I don't have a spare Windows PC.

Just incase someone has seen similar hardware its an [Aspire E5-573 Part Number NX.MVJEK.016](https://www.acer.com/us-en/support/product-support/E5-573/NX.MVJEK.016/downloads)

Is there any possible way to restore the EFI boot loader **without** using a bootable drive.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149198/discussion-on-question-by-philip-couling-is-there-any-way-to-restore-rebuild-e); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: If you have a valid ISO file could you boot and install Windows in a VM, and then use USB pass through to let that VM create a valid bootable stick using the proper Windows Media Creator?

Comment: @Mokubai yeah, I was going to try that this evening, but in the now moved comments, what's come out is the suggestion that I use third party boot software to chain load EFI. That should in theory work around the really stupid old firmware failing to understand the MS Windows ISO.  I'm still curious how cross-compatible the EFI binaries from Windows are, so I'll give the VM idea a go when I have a spare moment and write up the results here.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any possible way to restore the EFI boot loader without using a bootable drive?

No, there isn't.